# Organizar lista encadeada

Tags: c++

Olá estou tentando organizar uma lista encadeada simples mas estou perdendo a referência dos nós, se puderem me dar uma luz...
Por exemplo, se o nó anterior tiver o atributo "->data" maior que o posterior, eu devo trocá-los de lugar...

```
void organizarMenorMaior(node **ptrAux){ // recebe a cabeça do nó como parâmetro, ordena lista do menor para o maior 
    system("cls");
    node *p, *p2;
    p = *ptrAux;
    if(p==NULL){ // Verifica se a lista está vazia
        printf("Lista vazia!");
    }else{
        if(p->next==NULL){ // Verifica se a lista tem mais de 1 elemento
            printf("A lista tem apenas 1 elemento!");
        }else{
            p2 = p->next;
            if(p->data>p2->data){ // CORRIGIR AQUI, CONDIÇÃO NECESSÁRIA PAR FAZER A TROCA DE NÓS
                p->next = p2->next;
                p2->next = p;
            }else{
                printf("A lista ja esta organizada.\n");
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: O que está a tentar fazer é ordenar a lista ? Se for ordenação não dá para fazer só com `if` e sem *loops*

Comment: Eu gostaria de um exemplo apenas, estou ciente de que não é possível fazer sem loop...

Comment: Mas o objetivo é ordenar ? É que para mim não ficou claro. Se é o caso edite a pergunta e torne claro que pretende ordenar uma lista encadeada